# How to use two useParseQuery hook in back4app parse server for implementing one to one chat app

Tags: parse-platform, chat, back4app

i am trying to implement one to one chat on back4app server, i did not find any blog so going with my instinct.
i have made a class in database which has column from, to and message.
i trying to fetch from and to messages.
for that i using useParseQuery hook. How i can use this hook twice so that i can have message for both 'from' as well 'to'.

```
const App = () => {
const parseQuery1 = new Parse.Query('Chat_message');
parseQuery1.equalTo('from','amit');

const parseQuery2 = new Parse.Query('Chat_message');
parseQuery2.equalTo('to','amit');


const {
isLive,
isLoading,
isSyncing,
results,
count,
error,
reload
} = useParseQuery(parseQuery2);

console.log(results)
if (isLoading) {
return <ActivityIndicator />;
 }
 return (

  <FlatList
    data={results}
    
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 70,
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>message: {item.get('messages')}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
  );
 };
```

I do not know if my this approach is right, can some one enlighten or give some blog post for chat one to one. thank you good people of stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I used composeQuery.
i had tried with 'and' and that did not work eventually tried with or and that worked.

```
const parseQuery1 = new Parse.Query('Chat_message');
parseQuery1.equalTo('from','amit');

const parseQuery2 = new Parse.Query('Chat_message');
parseQuery2.equalTo('to','amit');

const composeQuery=Parse.Query.or(parseQuery2,parseQuery1)
```